# Visual Studio IDE On Class Diagram CANNOT USE / Add Or Drag/Drop file/Class Out Of Project Namespace

Tags: visual-studio, namespaces, ide, class-diagram

When using the VS-IDE Class Diagram, it is giving an error

> A Class With in Difference Namespace than Working Project

For example:

Solution NameSpace : Global.Project_A

1. `Project_A.Class` A1
2. `Global.Hardwares.ADeviceHelper`

> Cannot create class diagram for Global.Hardwares.ADeviceHelper class file with in Project_A

So my questions are:

- Has anyone a solution for this?
- I need to create another solution to create a class diagram for `ADeviceHelper`. How can I do this?